# Elastic Search Boosting Not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to boost the results, the Index(1), mapping(2) and the one working(3) and not working code(4) is shown in the image.

Why boosting is not working when using personalizationField1 instead of term.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post text, rather than an image? Also, it's better to [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- with Elasticsearch that would mean creating a new empty index, showing the mapping with just the fields you care about, and the doc(s) and query that illustrate the problem.

Comment: @GSH did you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use boost in a prefix query: [Elasticsearch 6.2 Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html)

> The boost is applied only for term queries (prefix, range and fuzzy
>   queries are not boosted).